# Error: `FileSystem.moveAsync` needs a `to` path. in react native (Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, expo, use-state

I am trying to take pictures from a real device and save it in a new location using expo `expo-file-system`. But I am getting an error `Error: FileSystem.moveAsync needs a to path.`

My code:

```
const fileMoveHandler = async () => {
    const fileName = selectedImage.split("/").pop();
    console.log("FileSystem:", FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName);
    setNewPathImage(FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName);
    console.log("newPathImage", newPathImage);
    try {
      await FileSystem.moveAsync({
        from: selectedImage,
        to: newPathImage,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error:", err);
      Alert.alert("Can't move this file.", "Try again!", [{ text: "Okay" }]);
    }
  };
```

Console.log:

```
FileSystem: file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/******/3061c494-6c3b-4307-abb3-a0d8681d2bb3.jpg

newPathImage undefined

Error: [Error: `FileSystem.moveAsync` needs a `to` path.]
```

As I am getting `newPathImage` undefined that's why it is giving me error but I don't know why I am getting undefined?

How can I set the state for the image path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be because `setState()` is asynchronous so when you try to set `to` to `newPathImage` it's still undefined. It should work if you do something like this instead:

```
const fileMoveHandler = async () => {
    const fileName = selectedImage.split("/").pop();
    const newPathImage = FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName
    console.log("FileSystem:", newPathImage);
    setNewPathImage(newPathImage);
    console.log("newPathImage", newPathImage);
    try {
      await FileSystem.moveAsync({
        from: selectedImage,
        to: newPathImage,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error:", err);
      Alert.alert("Can't move this file.", "Try again!", [{ text: "Okay" }]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Tried this. But I am getting the same issue. Still, it is undefined.

Comment: What is inside your console ?

Comment: ```FileSystem: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3727637A-7613-48BD-B913-14215CD4DF25/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540harsh_mishra%252FTravel/F2E74CDD-D670-49B1-A949-8695F97F73D2.jpg
newPath file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3727637A-7613-48BD-B913-14215CD4DF25/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540harsh_mishra%252FTravel/F2E74CDD-D670-49B1-A949-8695F97F73D2.jpg
newPathImage undefined```

Comment: This is what I am getting in console.

Comment: So `newPath` is not undefined from what I can see, did you set `to` to `newPath` instead of `newPathImage` ?

Comment: Yes, It's working fine if I set it `to` to `newPath`. But, I don't understand why setNewPathImage(newPath) doesn't work.

Comment: It actually works but it is asynchronous, so when you try to use `newPathImage` it's not updated yet. But you can show it inside your jsx (`<p>{newPathImage}</p>`) and when you will move your file you will see that its value has been updated.

Comment: Oh. I get it. Thanks for your help.